# Discrete Maths Question about Elements of Sets

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I just need help with this question below, im not sure how to find which elements are of both $X$ and $Y$.

**Consider the sets $X=\{5+9\mid\in\mathbb{Z}\}$ and $Y=\{15+14\mid\in\mathbb{Z}\}$.**

**Find an element of $$ which is also an element of $$.**

Comment: How would you find elements of $X$? How would you find elements of $Y$? Can you find a few in each set? Can you check if some of them are the same?

Comment: try writing out a bunch of elements in X and a bunch of elements in Y. you will quickly find one in common.

Comment: For $n=1$ we have that $5n+9=14$ while for $k=0$ we have that $15k+14=14$. How to find them? Considering the equation: $5n+9=15k+14$...